# Regular expression vs Apache regular expressions

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I had a situation where same pattern is working for Java and not working for Apache regular experssions API.

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import org.apache.oro.text.regex.MalformedPatternException;
import org.apache.oro.text.regex.PatternCompiler;
import org.apache.oro.text.regex.PatternMatcher;
import org.apache.oro.text.regex.Perl5Compiler;
import org.apache.oro.text.regex.Perl5Matcher;

public class PatternExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9\\p{Punct}]+");  //working
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("pass@1234");
        System.out.println("Input String matches regex - "+matcher.matches());
        match("pass@1234");
    }


    public static MatchResult match(String input) {
        PatternCompiler compiler = new Perl5Compiler();
        PatternMatcher matcher = new Perl5Matcher();
        org.apache.oro.text.regex.Pattern pattern = null;

        if (pattern == null) {
            try {
                pattern = compiler.compile("^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9\\p{Punct}]+");
            } catch (MalformedPatternException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
        if (matcher.matches(input, pattern)) {
            System.out.println("true");
        }else{
            System.out.println("false");
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Above code is giving output in two different ways inside main method pattern is working while match method is giving false.

**Basically my requirement is to allow Alphanumeric and some special characters in Java and JavaScript I am validating in JavaScript and again in Java Using Perl5Compiler.**

Javascript validation
    function _validatePasswordCharacter (/* Widget */ field){

```
    var regExp;
    var regExpInput = "^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9\\p{Punct}]+";
    console.log(regExpInput);
    try
    {
        regExp = new RegExp(regExpInput);
    }
    catch (Error)
    {
        console.debug('Error while parsing the password charset');

        return false;
    }

    if (!regExp.test(field.get('value')))
    {       
        console.debug('Password not matching regular expression check -- portal.properties');
        return false;
    } 
    else{
        console.debug('Password matching regular expression check -- portal.properties');
        return true;
    }

}
```

Please suggest to move forward

Comment: JavaScript? There is no JavaScript in here...

Comment: I don't know that {Punct} part; try (just as a test) to remove it and explicitly state what you want (in this case: `[!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~-]`)

Comment: [“Some people, when confronted with a problem, think ‘I know, I’ll use regular expressions.’   Now they have two problems.”](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)  Seriously, you can simplify things immensely by *not* trying to do it all in a single regular expression.  Doing it all in one line does not mean it will be faster or better.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing I believe Perl does not have the {Punct} class This regexp should work as intended:

`"^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~-]+"`